# Could the question "What movie takes place entirely underwater?" be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

I've asked this question 2 years ago that I'm trying to re-open now. It is a cinema history question that I really want to know the answer of.

[What movie takes place entirely underwater?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85497/what-movie-takes-place-entirely-underwater)

I've tried to update it to make it on-topic 2 years ago but it wasn't re-opened.

I've even updated further now and also included the similar questions that weren't closed. It is not an empty trivia question or a question about an unimportant detail in a movie. It pertains to the whole cinema history and the answer would help me further to understand the techniques used.

Could it be re-opened?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have cast the final reopen-vote along with a few tweaks to the question. It is certainly **surfing the fuzzy edge of list/first-appearance/has-there-ever questions, an edge worth guarding against useless lists based on random nonsense criteria**. All the existing close-votes were for "recommendation", which kind of makes sense as the go-to reason for list questions, but if we take a closer look at the actual question, we'll see it's a lot more than that.

The question makes a **strong point for it being a rare scenario (based on prior research) and for how that makes it relevant historically**. Therefore, it doesn't necessarily even have to strongly concentrate on the first-appearance aspect to make sense as a reasonable question, so I deliberately left it straddling between first-appearance and is-there-any, since while the latter can be a little open-ended, concentrating on the former would be just...bland. There is a good point made for there not being *any* to begin with.

However, this is *not* an invitation for random answers throwing a movie name at the wall and seeing what happens. You got a reopened question asking for a curiosity in film-making, now **give it the elaborate answers it deserves**. But I'd prefer policing the answers rather than shutting off a question that *does* go to the extra effort of separating itself from the random nonsense lists we *actually* discourage here.

For more discussion on the difficult question of what a list question even is and to which degree they *are* appropriate questions, [this old discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1060/49) might offer some insight, too.